# add two binary numbers

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise17 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long binary1, binary2;
        int i = 0, remainder = 0;
        int[] sum = new int[20];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input first binary number: ");
        binary1 = in.nextLong();
        System.out.print("Input second binary number: ");
        binary2 = in.nextLong();

        while (binary1 != 0 || binary2 != 0) {
            sum[i++] = ((binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + remainder) % 2);
            remainder = ((binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + remainder) / 2);
            binary1 = binary1 / 10;
            binary2 = binary2 / 10;
        }
        if (remainder != 0) {
            sum[i++] = remainder;
        }
        --i;
        System.out.print("Sum of two binary numbers: ");
        while (i >= 0) {
            System.out.print(sum[i--]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

I wrote on the paper I got  sum[1] = 0 sum[2] = 0 sum[3] = 1 sum[4] = 1 , but it told that --i. So now i = 3, sout(sum[i--]) .

The answer should be 00. because it bagan on sum(2) and sum(1).

Why the answer is not like the way I thing. Help me please.

Comment: What numbers did u try to add? And what result u got? Why u assume this code works wrong?

Comment: It is not wrong, but curious. - -i = 3  then it wrote sum[i- -], so it should be sum[2]. the while loop made it did 2 times. sum[2] and sum[1]. The answer that I wrote on paper on my understanding was 00, but the real answer was 1100. Can u teach me?

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're saying now. You were wondering why the output of the while loop started at index 3.

That is because inside the print statement of the while loop, you are using `i--`. That is actually the equivalent of this:

```
System.out.print(sum[i]);
i--;
```

The behaviour you are expecting would be achieved by using:

```java
System.out.print(sum[--i]);
```

That is equivalent to the following for loop:

```java
for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    System.out.print(sum[j]);
}
```

Comment: If i = 3,it will print out only 100, but the answer is 1100

Comment: Right, well, that doesn't line up with `The answer should be 00. because it bagan on sum(2) and sum(1)`. Mind answering Tomal's question as to which numbers you're trying to add, in the same format they're getting passed in?

Comment: What?? Can u explain for me ?